# How to estimate the complexity of a particular program

Tags: algorithm, matrix, memory, time-complexity, matrix-multiplication

**Problem:** Assume that the coefficients of A and B take (1) bits in memory, proving that, in the
worst case, the coefficients of the result of the sequence of products problem use ()
bits.

```
def product(A,B):
    """
    Computing the product of two given matrices
    
    Args:
    - A (tuple): a matrix of size 2 x 2
    - B (tuple): a matrix of size 2 x 2
    
    Return:
    - product (tuple): a product of two matrices A and B
    """
    
    product = []
    
    for i in range(2):
        row = []
        for k in range(2):
            row.append(A[i][0]*B[0][k] + A[i][1]*B[1][k])
        product.append(tuple(row))
        # print(row)
    return tuple(product)
```

```
def random_word(n):
    """
    Generate random words of length n from two letters A and B.
    Args:
    - n (integer): the length of the string
    Return: A random string of size n including A and B
    """
    return "".join(random.choice(['A', 'B']) for _ in range(n))
```

```
def naive(u, A, B):
    """
    Generating naive multiplication for matrix sequences.
    
    Args:
    - u (string): the given random word generated by random_word() function.
    - A (tuple): the given matrix A.
    - B (tuple): the given matrix B.
    
    Return: product of sequence of matrices including A and B.
    """
    sequence_product = identity()
    for k in u:
        if k == 'A':
            sequence_product = product(sequence_product,A)
        elif k == 'B':
            sequence_product = product(sequence_product,B)
    return sequence_product
```

Here is my attempt:Now, let's consider the worst-case scenario for the sequence of products. Suppose the input word $\bar{u}$ is of length $\bar{n}$. In the worst case, every character in $\bar{u}$ alternates between 'A' and 'B' (e.g., "ABABAB..."). In this case, the sequence of products would involve multiplying the matrices $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ alternatively.

In each multiplication operation, the coefficients of the resulting matrix are computed by adding products of constant-sized coefficients. Therefore, the coefficients of the result matrix in the worst case would be the sum of products of $\bar{n}$ constant-sized values.

Since the coefficients are constant-sized, the total number of bits required to represent the coefficients of the result matrix in the worst case is proportional to $\bar{n}$, i.e., $\overline{\Theta(n)}$.

To formalize this analysis, you can express the worst-case space complexity as $\Theta(n)$, indicating that the space required grows linearly with the size of the input word $\bar{n}$.

However, I cannot find any precise explanation for my estimation